# How can I write integration minitest code for a Rails app with basic authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, basic-authentication, minitest

About this matter, Rails guides and Rails documentation both didn't work. I wrote something like this and ran it

```
class PlacesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def test_places
    get root_url
    assert_response 200
  end
end
```

But I have this line on `application_controller.rb` file:

```
http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret"
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#what-to-include-in-your-functional-tests

This link suggests kindly

> If you followed the steps in the Basic Authentication section, you'll need to add the following to the setup block to get all the tests passing:

```
request.headers['Authorization'] = 
ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.
  encode_credentials('dhh', 'secret')
```

But it didn't work. Following link also suggests the same thing:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html

But still test didn't pass.

```
E

Error:
PlacesTest#test_places:
NoMethodError: undefined method `headers' for nil:NilClass
    test/integration/places_test.rb:6:in `setup'
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing `request` in controller tests is no longer supported in Rails 5, since controller test classes are inheriting from `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`, while they were inheriting from `ActionController::TestCase` in Rails 4.

To set request header in controller tests, you need to do this:

```
get root_url, headers: { 'Authorization': ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials('dhh', 'secret') }
```

Edit:
The guides are out-dated, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/52803443/7313509

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's funny because two questions on the same thing were asked on the same day (duplicated) I thought I looked everywhere, but even edgeapi has updated information... https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html