# How to test or bypass Basic Auth in Rails 5 testing of controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, testng, basic-authentication

I would like to test controllers in Rails 5 for which Basic Authentication is activated.
The way explained in the [current official instruction](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#what-to-include-in-your-functional-tests) (as of 2018-10-14) does not work for some reason.
The Q&A "[Testing HTTP Basic Auth in Rails 2.2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165478/testing-http-basic-auth-in-rails-2-2)" seems too old for Rails 5 (at least for the default).

Here is a simplified example to reproduce the case.
I made an Article model and related resources by scaffold from a fresh install of Rails (latest stable version 5.2.1):

```
bin/rails g scaffold Article title:string content:text
```

and added the basic auth function to the controller, following the [official guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#http-basic-authentication); then the ArticlesController is like this, which certainly works:

```
# /app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "user1", password: "pass"
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end
end
```

The [official instruction](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#what-to-include-in-your-functional-tests) explains the way to test basic authentication; you add
`request.headers['Authorization']` in the `setup` block in the test file of the controller, which I did:

```
# /test/controllers/articles_controller_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class ArticlesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    request.headers['Authorization'] =
      ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials("user1", "pass")
    @article = articles(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get articles_url
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

However, `bin/rails test` fails as follows:

```
# Running:

E

Error:
ArticlesControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
NoMethodError: undefined method `headers' for nil:NilClass
    test/controllers/articles_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:ArticlesControllerTest>'

bin/rails test test/controllers/articles_controller_test.rb:10
```

Clearly, `request` method returns nil, and hence `request.headers['Authorization']` fails.  It is the same if the statement is placed at the top of 'testing-index' block instead.

I have found `request` returns a proper value **after** `get articles_url` is run, but it is too late by that time; I mean, Authentication has already failed by that time (obviously).  With some googling, it seems some people use `@request` and `@response` for the purpose instead, but I have also found the they are exactly in the same situation as `request` (expectedly?), that is, they are nil before `get`.

What is the way to bypass or test Basic Auth in testing of controllers or integration tests in Rails 5?

**EDIT:**
"The [**current** official instruction](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#what-to-include-in-your-functional-tests) (as of 2018-10-14)" is apparently wrong.  See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52803228/how-to-test-or-bypass-basic-auth-in-rails-5-testing-of-controllers/52803443#52803443).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The testing docs [were incorrect](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33579) and [have been updated](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33602) but not yet released. The [updated docs](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ffc4703f22888dce0394fe0ab524a9e6cdc3c7e5/guides/source/testing.md) read:

> NOTE: If you followed the steps in the Basic Authentication section, you'll need to add authorization to every request header to get all the tests passing:
>
> ```
> post articles_url, params: { article: { body: 'Rails is awesome!', title: 'Hello Rails' } }, headers: { Authorization: ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials('dhh', 'secret') }
> ```

Comment: That's a perfect answer and explains!  I confirm it works; *n.b.*, for `get`, the `params` option is optional and so this works:  
`get articles_url, headers: { Authorization: ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials('dhh', 'secret') }`

Comment: A note (Rails 5.2.1): `delete` method fails silently (that is, it does not delete the specified record) with no warning when Basic Auth fails (such as, it is not given!), unlike `post` and `get`, where an explicit error message is issued.